# Android launch activity title displayed in recently opened applications instead of App name

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

My Android App has different name for "App name" and Launch "activity title" in android manifest. It displays fine on home screen but when I double tap Home button to invoke list of recently opened applications it displays Launch "activity title" instead of App Name. Here how my manifest looks like. Can anyone suggest how to fix this and display app name in recently open application?

-- AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:allowClearUserData="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" ===> "My App"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" ===> "Welcome to My App"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_header">

         <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" > ===> "My App"
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

-- Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

 @Override
 protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
}

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
}

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is so clear why this is happening.  **Main activity**  always called with **Implicit intents**. This means your component (activity) will call as a service.

This is how an implicit intent works

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBzzJ.png) Activity A creates an Intent with an action description and passes it to startActivity(). [2](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving) The Android System searches all **apps** for an intent filter that matches the intent. When a match is found, [3] the system starts the matching activity (Activity B) by invoking its onCreate() method and passing it the Intent.

[image]

. for more information about implicit intents read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Receiving)

This process done for your **main** activity and , because it has a separate name so the *recent app* shows its  `android:label="@string/title_activity_main"`

**Solution**

I think there is no way other than putting `android:label="@string/app_name"`

Comment: @Salaman..Thanks but still it doesn't resolve issue. If change label to app_name main activity title bar displays app_name instead of title_activity_main. Only workaround for this is to set title bar label via code which seems working.

Answer (score -1):

you can just type whatever you want here

android:label="My BadAss Game!"

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: in your manifest where it says android label, just type the name you want displayed.... like android:label="My BadAss Game!"

Comment: I am already doing this if you see manifest app_name -> "My App" and title_activity_main -> "Welcome to My App". It displays fine on home screen but when i check recently open application instead of app name it shows main activity title.

Comment: @La5t5tarfighter please review the question